# Does selectedMenuItemStyle in material-ui work?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use selectedMenuItemStyle of the menu component as per [material-ui documentation](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/menu):

`<Menu
   onItemTouchTap={ this.handleRequestClose }
   selectedMenuItemStyle={ { backgroundColor: '#c00', 'background-color': '#c00', color: '#cc0000' } } >
// ....
</Menu>`

I tried with both the property backgroundColor and 'background-color' and a bunch of others, but it doesn't look to work: am I missing something, or is the documentation about a non-existing feature? I see there is some discussion about it in github and so on..

Answer (score 0):

Material UI recognise whether the menu item is selected

> If multiple is true, an array of the values of the selected menu
>   items. **Otherwise, the value of the selected menu item.** If provided,
>   the menu will be a controlled component. This component also supports
>   valueLink.

Here is the example, with hardcoded to select the first item:

```
      <Menu
        onItemTouchTap={ this.handleRequestClose }
        selectedMenuItemStyle={ {backgroundColor: '#c00', color: '#FFFFFF'} }
        value='1'
        >
          <MenuItem primaryText="Maps" value='1'/>
          <MenuItem primaryText="Books" value='2' />
      </Menu>
```

In real application, you should use this as 'controlled component' in order to make use of this inline style.